# MVC 4 Profile error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, profile

I'm working on MVC 4 application. I have to show picture profile on all pages when the user is authentified.

I try to use code found here : [.net profile provider and custom profiles. The settings property '' was not found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298981/net-profile-provider-and-custom-profiles-the-settings-property-was-not-foun) to implement Profile properties. but i got an error !

my profile class :

```
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Toombu
{
    public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
    {
        public static ProfileCommon GetUserProfile(string username)
        {
            return Create(username) as ProfileCommon;
        }

        public static ProfileCommon GetUserProfile()
        {
            var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
            return Create(membershipUser.UserName) as ProfileCommon;
        }

        [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
        public string Picture
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Picture"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                base["Picture"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my Webconfig file, I supose that i made an error here, but i don't know where.

```
<profile inherits="Toombu.ProfileCommon">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ToombuContext"/>
    </providers>
</profile>
```

i use a sqlServer database. my connectionstring :

```
<add name="ToombuContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=toombu;Integrated Security=SSPI;;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My view :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img style="width: 20px;-webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px;" src="@ProfileCommon.GetUserProfile().Picture" />
    </a>
}
```

i got this error :

```
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Did you install the ASP.NET Membership database?

Comment: No ! I want to use my own Database. I have Membership and role tables in it. Is it possible ?

Comment: It is my understanding that when you specify your provider as `AspNetSqlProfileProvider` that implies that you have installed the ASP.NET Membership tables and supporting stored procs into your database in order to store the Membership/Profile data.

Comment: I'm confused. I found SqlProvider too. I don't know the differences between them and witch one choose ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research into the different providers and the requirements and restrictions of each one